# C++ PEXT/PDEP implementations

Tags: c++, performance

The common implementations usually reference: https://github.com/fmatthew5876/stdcxx-bitops/blob/master/include/bitops.hh

I styled my version to match (except for the `constexpr` macro):

```
template <typename Integral>
constexpr Integral extract_bits(Integral x, Integral mask) {
   Integral res=0;
   int bb=1;

   do {
        Integral lsb=mask & -mask;
        mask &= ~lsb;
        bool isset=x & lsb;
        res |= isset ? bb : 0;
        bb+=bb;
    } while (mask);
        
  return res;
}

template <typename Integral>
constexpr Integral deposit_bits(Integral x, Integral mask) {
  Integral res = 0;
  int bb=1;

  do {
        Integral lsb=mask & -mask;
        mask &= ~lsb;
        bool isset=x&bb;
        res |= (x & bb) ? lsb : 0;
        bb+=bb;
  } while(mask);
  return res;
}
```

Comment: So it looks like you took Matthew Fioravante's version and turned the `for`-loop in a `do`-`while` loop, and the `if` into a ternary? I'm not really sure this is suitable for Code Review.

Comment: Its the result of quite a bit of optimizing. Take a look at https://godbolt.org/z/3TqeerMzc

Comment: Yes, I did see the difference in assembly output, and with your changes it is indeed a bit better. However, if you are not the author of the code you post, it's not considered [on-topic](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) for CodeReview..

Comment: ownership can be discussed here: https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10829/how-much-modification-is-needed-to-be-considered-authoring-the-code

Comment: I don't see any macro.  Did you intend to write "the `constexpr` _keyword_" there?

Comment: The original used a macro, I directly used `constexpr`